# Kernel panic: error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2

Tags: server, kernel

The Ubuntu Server from one moment to another generate this problem. I see that on some forums and YouTube's videos say that live recovery CD can solve the problem:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Which Ubuntu Server version? Do you have libcap2 package installed?

Comment: Inicie con la 16.04 y paulatinamente iba actualizando creo que ya estaba con los directorios del 18.10 bionic.